# Classical Electrodynamics vs Quantum Electrodynamics: Orbits and Eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics

Thanks for reading this possible simple question. In classical electrodynamics, we describe charges moving in an electromagnetic (EM) field, and for different initial conditions, we can obtain different "trajectories" and "orbits." However, in quantum electrodynamics (QED), the concepts of "trajectories" and "orbits" are replaced by "probability distributions" and "eigenstates." (if this mapping is incorrect, please explain why.)

I am interested in understanding the connection between these classical and quantum descriptions - particularly how to interpret the classical "orbit" in the context of quantum "eigenstates" and how to connect the classical energy and the quantum energy eigenvalue?

Most quantum mechanics or QED textbooks I have encountered do not provide closely related chapters on this topic. I would appreciate any lecture recommendations or further resources that might help clarify this comparison.

During my research, I found that the old quantum theory, specifically the Bohr–Sommerfeld quantization, seems to be related to my question. However, I am struggling to extend this concept to arbitrary trajectories and orbits, which is easily achieved in classical electrodynamics by adjustifing the related parameters.

Comment: One of the big mysteries of late 19th century physics was explaining how atoms could be stable. Using classical physics, an accelerated electron radiates energy. An orbit around a nucleus is accelerated. The electron should spiral into the nucleus in a small fraction of a second. This was one of the motivations to look beyond classical physics.

Comment: In my opinion, when you meticulously correlate pairs of particles and subject them to testing and obtain results that align with COS2THETA or Malus Law, you are inclined to seek a classical/physical explanation. However, if you find yourself unable to explain the phenomena, you might attribute it to quantum mechanics statistics and refrain from further pursuit of understanding.

Comment: You appear interested in the classical limit of quantum mechanics. It is most transparent in the [phase-space formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation), and not the Hilbert space one you are starting with. Look at the movies there, that should be self-explanatory....

Comment: You can find several articles about highly excited atoms (Rydberg atoms) that are analyzing exactly this question both theoretically and experimentally. There is even an article from the late 1920s by Heisenberg, I believe, where he discusses the quantum-classical transition as a weak measurement phenomenon on the example of Rydberg atoms (I forgot the exact citations, sorry). This system has obviously fascinated physicists very early on. Needless to say, one can construct superpositions of states with high angular momentum that show "classical orbital motion".